# Derivative of delta function integrated from 0 to infinity

Tags: integration, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I am aware this is not a perfectly rigorous question, but bear in mind I am a physicist (though I would be open to a rigorous discussion). Suppose I want to integrate a function $f$ together with the delta function derivative kernel $δ$'($x$), but instead of integrating from minus to plus infinity, I want to do it from $0$ to $\infty$.

I am realizing this is not entirely rigorous, and probably the right way to discuss it is working with the distribution u$δ$', where u is the Heaviside distribution. But then again I believe the product of the distributions is ill defined. So how do I do it, assuming f is a test function that vanishes close to $x=0$?

Comment: Usually, the Dirac delta comes from some kind of limit in physics. If you get a ill-defined distribution, it usually means one of the limit was wrong before. Remember that limits and product do not commute.

Answer (score 1):

The Dirac Delta is not a function and the linear functional that is often represented by an integral is not an integral.

If $f$ is a suitable test function (i.e., $f\in C_C^\infty$), then we have

$$\langle \delta, f\rangle=f(0)$$

However, $fH$ is not a suitable test function since it is not continuous at the origin.  And both $\langle \delta,fH\rangle$ and $\langle \delta H,f\rangle$ are ill-defined.

To see this, let $\delta_n$ be the sequence of functions defined for any number $0<a<1$, as

$$\delta_n=\begin{cases}n&,x\in (-a/n,(1-a)/n)\\\\0&,\text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

Then, for any suitiable test function $f$ we have clearly that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta_n(x) f(x)\,dx=f(0)$$

We call $\delta_n$ a regularization of the Dirac Delta. Now, let's apply this regularization to the function $fH$, which is equivalent to applying $\delta_n H$ to the test function $f$.  Proceeding, we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta_n(x)f(x)H(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{(1-a)/n}nf(x)dx=(1-a)f(0)$$

Inasmuch as this result depends on the value of $a$, the limit is not uniquely defined and $\delta H$ is, therefore, not a distribution.

Comment: The original question was asking about the *derivative* of the delta.

Comment: Situation is even worse then

Comment: @LL3.14 Yes indeed.  Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @JohnBarber If $\delta H$ is not a distribution, then neither is $\delta' H$.  And this can be shown in an analogous way to that of the posted solution herein.  Does that suffice?